# How to remove default Laravel Exception message from Custom Exception message

Tags: php, laravel

I have this get organisations method in one project that talks to a central api project that handles all data like so:

```
public function searchOrganisations()

{
    try {
        return $this->client->request(.....);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        
    }
}
```

Within the api project a method is then hit and if a certain time frame criteria is hit I throw a custom exception like so:

```
public function searchOrganisations($searchRequest)
    {
        $experianCutOff = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '06:00:00');
        $now = Carbon::now()->setTime(02, 0, 0);

        if (!$now->lt($experianCutOff)) {

            return $data
        } else {

            throw new ExperianServiceException();
        }
    }
```

My custom exeption is as follows:

```
class ExperianServiceException extends Exception
{
    public function render() {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'The Experian Service is currently unavailable, please try again at 0600 GMT'
          ], 503);
    }
}
```

This works as expected and I catch the exception in the first method listed, I can access the status 503 and can see the message, however the message property of the exception always comes back in this format:

```
Server error: `POST http://docker.../search-organisations` resulted in a `503 Service Unavailable` response:
{"message":"The Experian Service is currently unavailable, please try again at 0600 GMT"}
```

It seems as though my supplied custom message has been concatenated with the standard Laravel Exception message (which I dont want). How can I make sure my message only contains what I supplied in my custom exception?

Comment: Would I then have to do something like `ExperianServiceException('My Message', 503)`?

Comment: just create your own `503.blade.php` file inside `resources/views/errors` as `resources/views/errors/503.blade.php` then it will throw 503 error from this page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have your Exception implement `Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Responsable` and define the `toResponse` method to return that response. When you only have the `render` method the framework is still **potentially** going to do things to prepare the response. If it is `Responsable` it calls `toResponse` on it and returns that directly.

This causes a raw response from `toResponse` of your Exception to be returned without passing through any other parts of the Handler to be prepared in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
 return Response::json(array(
                'code'      =>  404,
                'message'   =>  $message
            ), 404);
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27276005).